# Should the choice of text encoding when saving files always match the encoding specified in the declarations of the xml document?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core

For example, we created an xml document, opened it and write Cyrillic characters inside some element and saved it as utf-8. But you indicate windows-1251 encoding in the xml declaration
The same when sending an http request

Comment: Why would you use anything other than UTF8? That's just begging for trouble. There has to be a *very* good reason to use another encoding. `That's how we do it` isn't a valid one - or even true

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: obviously, because sometimes it is a requirement, and you cannot affect it.

Comment: Saving in UTF-8 will not modify the Win 1251 characters.

Comment: @Dennis not obvious at all. `Because potato` isn't a valid reason. `Because that's how we do it` isn't either, and they don't - all web sites are UTF8 for example, so are most APIs. `Because UFT8 is broken` means the application is broken. `Because we didn't know we could fix this` is usually the only reason, and the answer is `Fix this`

Comment: I work with the same requirement every day. This requirement comes from legislator. Should I teach them to use UTF-8, because "most APIs" use UTF-8, or should just use their requirement as is? :)

Comment: Dennis I work in a country (Greece) that doesn't use the Latin alphabet, so we had to solve this in the 1990s. Eventually they learned. Not that they even realized people were already using UTF8. Besides, ASP.NET Core should be able to handle any encoding. Which means the only question is how to tell the XmlSerializer what encoding to use, assuming that isn't passed automatically

Comment: What kind of application is this and how is the XML generated? As a response to an API call? Generated as a document in code? If you add the XML response formatters to ASP.NET Core it should return XML if the request asks for it and *probably* handle the encoding as well.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: you asked OP about *why do they use non-UTF-8 encoding*. I gave you an example why - because it could be an external requirement. You told "change the external requirement". Ok. I see your point. But in my case this is impossible. I suppose OP has the same problems.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it is external requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual text encoding must match encoding in XML declaration.

if you use UTF-8 in XML declaration, then save the file using UTF-8 encoding.
If there's Windows-1251 in XML declaration, then save the file using Windows-1251.

XML declaration doesn't force serializer to "turn on" right encoding on deserialization/serialization. You need to tell serializer, which encoding to use during reading or writing the file.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, and did so